# Regex lookbehind is invalid with a vertical bar ( | ), but regex lookahead works just fine in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I want to match 子 in these examples in Notepad++

`(1) し子
(2) かり子
(3) 子し
(4) 子かり`

A lookahead such as `子(?=かり|[しつ])` perfectly matches it at line (3) and (4), with no problem. But a lookbehind such as `(?<=かり|[しつ])子` for some reason is invalid and can't match it at line (1) and (2) at all, even though individually `(?<=かり)子` and `(?<=[しつ])子` work just fine. Why's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your negative lookbehind has variable length (either 2 characters  `かり` or one character `[しつ]`, and variable length lookbehinds are not supported by most regex engines, including the one in Notepad++. If you can remove the first character from the lookbehind (`か`) i.e.

```
(?<=り|[しつ])子
```

or more optimally

```
(?<=[りしつ])子
```

It will work, although it will match `子` preceded by `り` and any character. If that is not acceptable, you could use a capturing group instead i.e.

```
(かり|[しつ])子
```

and include `$1` in your replacement

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw Just noticed a typo which I have corrected (extra `[` in the second regex)